# Wix Toolset Check for .Net 4.6.2

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I am using Wix Toolset v3.10.3 and I am trying to get my MSI to check if .Net 4.6.2 is installed on the machine

According to the page [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html) I should be able to use the following property

```
<PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_462_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"/>
```

and then do something like this

```
    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.6.2. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again. If you require assistance, please contact [company name] support">
          <![CDATA[Installed OR WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_462_OR_LATER_INSTALLED]]>
</Condition>
```

but when I build I am getting the following error

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_462_OR_LATER_INSTALLED' in section 'Product:*'.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on this one? I can see that the .net 4.X family of propeties are different but I cant see that I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Do you have a reference to WixNetFxExtension.dll?

Comment: Yes I do, its coming from C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin and shows version 3.10.3.3007 in the dll properties. Interestinglyenough, the Visual Studio propeties window shows the reference as version  3.0.0.0 (it looks like it does this for all the WiX Modules I have referenced)

Comment: I have the same issue, WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED works fine.  But 461 and 462 both fail with same error as shown above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED` is supported in WiX v3.10.3. `WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_461_OR_LATER_INSTALLED` and `WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_462_OR_LATER_INSTALLED` are supported in WiX v3.11.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  Good thing this is a 3-day weekend (Columbus Day), so we should expect a v3.11 release, right?<g>

Comment: Amazing thanks Bob thats solved my issue! I was confused as the docs showed the property and the latest stable release was v3.10.3

Comment: The doc on the Web site is from the `develop` branch of the `wix3` repo, so it reflects the current development of WiX v3.x (in this case v3.11).

Comment: Hi Bob, I understand that this is an old answer but I give it a try anyways. v3.11 is to my knowledge still counted as not stable. 

Do you have any knowledge on when it will be counted as stable?

Comment: @MikaelJohansson I know you posted this comment a few months ago, so apologies for the late response, but WiX v3.11 is now stable and can be found here - http://wixtoolset.org/releases/